# Is there a terminal command that will click the mouse?

Tags: xorg

I am looking for a way to click the mouse, as it is in its current location or in a  specific location on the screen, after *x* minutes. Is there any way to do this with a terminal command (preferably with the programs Ubuntu has installed by default)?

Comment: Ubuntu comes with Python, and because Python is the swiss-knife (or is that Perl?). No, Python is the glue. So look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545230/simulate-mouse-clicks-on-python

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes there is `xdotool`. `xdotool` is a automation tool from X11. To install it type

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

To click the mouse via terminal command type:

```
xdotool click <button>
```

where button is 1 for left mouse button, 2 for middle, 3 for right, 4 for wheel up and 5 for wheel down.

So a click with the left mouse button is:

```
xdotool click 1
```

To move the mouse to a specific position on the screen type

```
xdotool mousemove 120 100
```

So the mouse is moved 120 pixels right and 100 pixels down from the top left corner of the screen.

If you want to use this in a cron job (to repeat this every x minutes), don't forget to populate the `$DISPLAY` environment variable in your crontab.

Comment: Do you know how to run this command inside a desktop (e.g. Mate or Gnome)? For example, if I set this command to a keyboard shortcut in Mate it doesn't do anything. It only works if I execute it at command line.

Comment: You need to set the `$DISPAY` variable. Something like this: `DISPLAY=:0 xdotool click 1`